# Generate the public key and encode the plain text

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

Let the alphabet be identified with $0,... 25$. In order to decrypt a plain text via RSA, we have prime numbers $p=53$ and $q=13$. Additionally we have $e=11$.
Generate the public key and encode the plain text: GEDULD

---

$p=53, q=13$

$N=p \cdot q = 689$

$r=(p-1) \cdot (q-1)=624$

We have $e=11$ so the public key is $(11,624)$?

Is this correct? But how to do the encryption with the word? I have no idea :s

Comment: You simply need to get the plaintext into numerical format.  It doesn't really matter how this is done so long as the chosen algorithm is bijective: given any plaintext, there is a unique numeric value, and to each numeric value, there is a unique plaintext.  Look up ASCII, e.g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public key appears to be $(e, N) = (11, 689)$, but you give us a notation without explanation, so perhaps $e$ is meant to be the decrypting exponent, so you have to calculate the encrypting exponent via a gcd calculation, who knows?

Encryption depends on whether you encrypt one letter at a time, or two at a time, as you might be able to do here, as $26^2 < 689$. Again, you only know, and this depends also on the way you pack two letters in a single number. We cannot possibly know until you tell us.